# JNI_OnLoad error: Unable to find decl for native function with signature ()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I'm currently using SWIG/jni to call C++ functions from java for an Android app. However, I'm having difficulty whenever the function returns a jstring. I get the following errors in LogCat upon application launch...

**ERROR**: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/example/swigJNI;.plugin_name:L()java/lang/String

**ERROR**: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/example/swigJNI;.plugin_description:L()java/lang/String

Here is some code that might be useful to examine...

SWIG generated wrapper code:

```
 SWIGEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_swigJNI_1plugin_1name(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
  jstring jresult = 0 ;
  char *result = 0 ;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  result = (char *)plugin_name();
  if (result) jresult = jenv->NewStringUTF((const char *)result);
  return jresult;
}


SWIGEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_swigJNI_1plugin_1description(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass     jcls) {
  jstring jresult = 0 ;
  char *result = 0 ;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  result = (char *)plugin_description();
  if (result) jresult = jenv->NewStringUTF((const char *)result);
  return jresult;
}
```

Declaration of JNI Native methods:

```
static const JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"plugin_name", "()Ljava/lang/String", (void*) Java_swigJNI_1plugin_1name},
    {"plugin_description", "()Ljava/lang/String", (void*) Java_swigJNI_1plugin_1description}
};
```

I've been successful in executing JNI_onLoad() and RegisterNatives() when the functions return int's, however strings have been quite problematic for me. I don't quite understand how these functions aren't being found. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, I feel like a fool!

The signature I was using for string was...

```
()Ljava/lang/String
```

when it should really be...

```
()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Forgot the semi-colon. Ack!

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the header file of your java class(generated c header file) in c++ code, where the native method is defined.

so, generate a C header file, containing the function prototype for the native method implementation

Comment: Yes, I declared each native function in a file (plugin.h), which I included at the top of the SWIG generated C++ wrapper. I'm starting to think that this may be an issue with C++ strings and Android's NDK...